# MYSQL update query to remove spaces

Tags: mysql, sql-update

One of my clients has added a number of account numbers in one of our applications.
While trying to make a transaction the transaction fails due to the spaces at the end of the account number.
How do i update his records in the Mysql database to remove all the spaces from accounts that have them at the end, without making him delete the clients and re-adding the accounts? the structure of the table(s) is as follows:

Not sure how to structure the query or the function of the mysql

The account table:

```
the account table:
CUSTOMER_ID              
ACCOUNTNUMBER        
TXT                   
CURRENCY_NO            
USER_ID                  
ACTIVE_FLAG               
USER_DATE                 
ben_bic_address          
int_bic_address 

the admin table

  ADM_USER_ID           
  LOCATION_CD          
  LANG                
  USER_NAME              
  USER_LOGIN            
  USER_PASSWORD          
 GROUP_CODE            
 USER_ID              
  USER_DATE               
  ACTIVE                 
 COUNTER                
 connected              
 IP

And the customer table:

CUSTOMER_ID               
COUNTRY_NO              
USER_ID                   
CUSTOMER_NAME 
ACTIVE_FLAG
```

Comment: Refer this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281724/does-the-mysql-trim-function-not-trim-line-breaks-or-carriage-returns

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you need to `RTRIM()` all the accounts of a particular customer, you can use a `JOIN` with your UPDATE statement as follows:

```
UPDATE
    accounts_table
INNER JOIN
    customers_table ON (accounts_table.user_id = customers_table.user_id)
SET 
    accountnumber = RTRIM(accountnumber)
WHERE
    customers_table.customer_id = 'customer id';
```

If you do not have many records in accounts_table, and you want to make sure that all the `accountnumber` values are trimmed, you can simply apply the trim to all the records as follows:

```
UPDATE
    accounts_table
SET 
    accountnumber = TRIM(accountnumber);
```

Comment: THANKS
i tried that but i get the following  error 
Error Code : 1305
FUNCTION abc1234.TRIM does not exist

Comment: @andreas: Make sure you do not have a space between the `TRIM` and the parenthesis `(`. It should be `TRIM(field)` not `TRIM (field)`.

Answer (score 8):

You would use TRIM and update.

Just using this should do it.

```
UPDATE accountTable
SET ACCOUNTNUMBER = RTrim(ACCOUNTNUMBER)
```

Comment: THANKS i tried that but i get the following error Error Code : 1305 FUNCTION abc1234.TRIM does not exist –

Comment: Take a look at this for ways to fix: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9051   You basically need to make sure you are using the correct cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you have foreign key constraints, then you may have to remove them whilst you make the modifications.

The following query will change the records in the accounts table:

```
update accounts set accountnumber = rtrim(accountnumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**TRIM() Function removes extra (or) additional spaces from a string.**

```
UPDATE item_listing SET product_quantity = TRIM(product_quantity);
```

**Result:**

Product_quantity = "     50   " => **50**