# MySQL select fields containing leading or trailing whitespace

Tags: mysql, sql, trim

I can use the MySQL `TRIM()` method to cleanup fields containing leading or trailing whitespace with an `UPDATE` like so:

```
UPDATE Foo SET field = TRIM(field);
```

I would like to actually see the fields this will impact before this is run. I tried this but returns 0 results:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE field != TRIM(field);
```

Seems like this should work but it does not.

Anyone have a solution? Also, curious why this does not work...

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2363449/1618257  ALSO, for `!=`, try `<>`

Comment: @David: `!=` vs `<>` does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: eggyal explained about trailing spaces.  Given your query results, it's safe to assume that none of your values had leading spaces.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As documented under [The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html):

> All MySQL collations are of type `PADSPACE`. This means that all `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` values in MySQL are compared without regard to any trailing spaces.

In the definition of the [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator, the manual states:

> In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for [`CHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html) or [`VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html) comparisons performed with the [`=`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal) operator:

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1947694/623041):

> This behavior is specified in SQL-92 and SQL:2008. For the purposes of comparison, the shorter string is padded to the length of the longer string.
>
> From the draft (8.2 <comparison predicate>):
>
> > If the length in characters of X is not equal to the length in characters of Y, then the shorter string is effectively replaced, for the purposes of comparison, with a copy of itself that has been extended to the length of the longer string by concatenation on the right of one or more pad characters, where the pad character is chosen based on CS. If CS has the NO PAD characteristic, then the pad character is an implementation-dependent character different from any character in the character set of X and Y that collates less than any string under CS. Otherwise, the pad character is a <space>.

One solution:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(field) != CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(field))
```

Comment: **All MySQL collations are of type  PADSPACE**

this is not correct. Default collation of mysql 8, has no pad space. This means 'stack ' != 'stack' . Both are different.

Comment: @simplifiedDB: Not according to https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b3DUfdgwbpxFKZf5WhR471/1

Comment: You need to set the default collation of utf8mb4 before running the mentioned query

set names utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
SELECT 'stack ' = 'stack';

Comment: Aha, got it!  MySQL 8.0 introduced collations based on UCA versions from 9.0.0 onward and those collations are NOPAD; all collations based on earlier UCA versions, including all that were available on earlier versions of MySQL, were PADSPACE (see [Collation Pad Attributes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html#charset-unicode-sets-pad-attributes)).  Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 43):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    `foo`
WHERE 
   (name LIKE ' %')
OR 
   (name LIKE '% ')
```

Comment: CORRECT! As per this well documented idiosyncrasy in MySQL, `LIKE` respects leading and trailing whitespace, where as `=` does not: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64772

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example with [RegEx](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    `foo`
WHERE 
   (name REGEXP '(^[[:space:]]|[[:space:]]$)')
```

Comment: @PatrickBassut Assuming, by whitespace the OP meant [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) rather than just U+0020, this is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be using [`SUBSTRING()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and `IN` to compare the last and first characters of the string with a list of whitespace charaters...

```sql
(SUBSTRING(@s,  1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r') OR SUBSTRING(@s, -1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r'))
```

...where `@s` is any input string. Add additional whitespace characters to the comparison list as needed in your case.

Here's a simple test to demonstrate how that expression behaves with various string inputs:

```sql
SET @s_normal = 'x';
SET @s_ws_leading = '\tx';
SET @s_ws_trailing = 'x ';
SET @s_ws_both = '\rx ';

SELECT
    NOT(SUBSTRING(@s_normal,      1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r') OR SUBSTRING(@s_normal,     -1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r')) test_normal      #=> 1 (PASS)
  ,    (SUBSTRING(@s_ws_leading,  1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r') OR SUBSTRING(@s_ws_leading, -1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r')) test_ws_leading  #=> 1 (PASS)
  ,    (SUBSTRING(@s_ws_trailing, 1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r') OR SUBSTRING(@s_ws_trailing,-1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r')) test_ws_trailing #=> 1 (PASS)
  ,    (SUBSTRING(@s_ws_both,     1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r') OR SUBSTRING(@s_ws_both,    -1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r')) test_ws_both     #=> 1 (PASS)
;
```

If this is something you'll be doing a lot you could also create a function for it:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS has_leading_or_trailing_whitespace;

CREATE FUNCTION has_leading_or_trailing_whitespace(s VARCHAR(2000))
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
  DETERMINISTIC
RETURN (SUBSTRING(s, 1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r') OR SUBSTRING(s, -1, 1) IN (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r'))
;

# test
SELECT
    NOT(has_leading_or_trailing_whitespace(@s_normal     )) #=> 1 (PASS)
  ,     has_leading_or_trailing_whitespace(@s_ws_leading )  #=> 1 (PASS)
  ,     has_leading_or_trailing_whitespace(@s_ws_trailing)  #=> 1 (PASS)
  ,     has_leading_or_trailing_whitespace(@s_ws_both    )  #=> 1 (PASS)
;
```