# Comparison with trailing spaces in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This SQL query:

```
select c1 from table where c1='';
```

returns rows that have `c1=' '` (one empty space) in MySQL.

Is this intended or a bug?

EDIT: please check SQL Fiddle link [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40e84/2), and the number of spaces in `SELECT` query doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you share an sql fiddle?

Comment: Are you sure it is SPACE and not TAB?

Comment: What is the result of "SELECT c1 from table where CHAR_LENGTH(c1) = 0"?

Comment: The data type of `c1` and your version of MySQL should be in the question.

Comment: Easy to reproduce. This is how SQL Server works too http://rextester.com/KSB84112

Comment: @1000111 yes, please check my edited question again.

Comment: Related question ['MySQL select fields containing leading or trailing whitespace'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16724574)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all stated there in the documentation. I've quoted the important points here. But I would suggest to go through the full [**documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html)

> VARCHAR values are not padded when they are stored. Trailing spaces
>   are retained when values are stored and retrieved, in conformance with
>   standard SQL.
>
> On the other hand, CHAR values are padded when they are stored but
>   trailing spaces are ignored when retrieved.

[image]

> All MySQL collations are of type PADSPACE. This means that all CHAR,
>   VARCHAR, and TEXT values in MySQL are compared without regard to any
>   trailing spaces. “Comparison” in this context does not include the
>   LIKE pattern-matching operator, for which trailing spaces are
>   significant.

**Explanation:** `Trailing spaces` are ignored while comparing strings using comparison operator ('='). But trailing spaces are significant for `LIKE` (`pattern matching operator`)

Comment: I saw your explanation, and I have this exact problem, I have a trailing space in one field but my like '% ' script somehow doesn't catch it. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Can you check the length of the string and be certain about your claim? `select length(string) ; select char_length(string)` @VladimirDespotovic

Comment: i did. All bad. Not good. It is completely wrong also when you compare string length using LENGTH()

Comment: Did you try with `char_length` too? @VladimirDespotovic 
You'd better share an SQLFIDDLE putting your mysterious data there. It will be easier to reproduce the problem then.

Answer (score 3):

If your column is from type **CHAR** and not VARCHAR, than this is correct.
On CHAR-Fields will trailing blanks on comparing ignored!
So

```
field = ''
field = '    '
```

are the same.

Comment: Actually this is not quite true. VARCHAR doesn't "ignore" trailing blanks. If you add them, they will be there. But CHAR fields are fixed width. So a CHAR(5) field will **always** be 5 chars (filled with blanks if necessary).

Comment: I am using `varchar`

Comment: @boh Trailing whitespace is ignored when comparing with `=`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar That's what I guess but I can't confirm, would appreciate if you can give a reference source, thanks.

Comment: @Thorsten the question is a SELECT Not a INSERT.

Comment: @Frank Well, you inserted "on comparing" in your last edit. Only that makes your answer correct. Still, when you select a `CHAR(5)` field, the result will always be 5 characters, not matter how long the actual content is. This is different with `VARCHAR` fields.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented behaviour.

The MySQL documentation for `LIKE` mentions

> trailing spaces are significant, **which is not true for CHAR or
>   VARCHAR comparisons performed with the = operator:**

[SQL Server works the same way.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/316626)

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is in accordance with ANSI SQL-92 standard. Any database conforming to this standard will exhibit same behavior. Quote:

> ```
> 3) The comparison of two character strings is determined as fol-
>    lows:
>
>    a) If the length in characters of X is not equal to the length
>      in characters of Y, then the shorter string is effectively
>      replaced, for the purposes of comparison, with a copy of
>      itself that has been extended to the length of the longer
>      string by concatenation on the right of one or more pad char-
>      acters, where the pad character is chosen based on CS. If
>      CS has the NO PAD attribute, then the pad character is an
>      implementation-dependent character different from any char-
>      acter in the character set of X and Y that collates less
>      than any string under CS. Otherwise, the pad character is a
>      <space>.
>
>    b) The result of the comparison of X and Y is given by the col-
>      lating sequence CS.
> ```

So, according to these specs `'abc' = 'abc '` and `'' = ' '` evaluate to true (but `'' = '\t'` is false).

Answer (score 1):

If `c1` is `CHAR(1)`, then this is correct, as `CHAR` columns are **fixed width** and will be filled with blanks if necessary.

So even if you put `''` into a `CHAR(1)` field you will get `' '` upon `SELECT`ing. Also, filtering for an empty string will yield `' '`.

**Please accept Martin Smith's answer, as he gave the correct hint before me**.

<strike>Also, as per [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), trailing whitespace is ignored when comparing strings with `=`, so if your `c1` column contains only spaces (or one in your case), it will be returned even though you filter `WHERE c1 = ''`:</strike>

> In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for CHAR or VARCHAR comparisons performed with the = operator

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'a ', 'a' LIKE 'a ';
+------------+---------------+
| 'a' = 'a ' | 'a' LIKE 'a ' |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             0 |
+------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't notice your answer until now. Going to remove this and lead to your answer, as this is the correct solution!

Answer (score -2):

```
select c1, length(c1) as l
from table t_name 
group by l
```

(figur eht oot)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -3):

Try this -

```
Select case when c1 = '' then ' ' else c1 end from table ;
```

Comment: What's this supposed to help?

Comment: It will convert your empty **('')**  to **' '** . Else it will return whatever string you have in that column.

I think it was asked in this  ?

Comment: Why would you want that? The original question is not to return `' '` when the column is empty but why `WHERE c1 = ''` also returns columns that contain `' '`. So no, this is not an answer to the question. Please read the question again.