# Does Mysql omit trailing whitespaces?

Tags: mysql, whitespace

Does anyone know what is the reason of my mysql giving the same results for:

```
select * from table where column = "xyz"
```

and

```
select * from table where column = "xyz "
```

(but

```
select * from table where column = " xyz"
```

not equals to

```
select * from table where column = "xyz";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724574/mysql-select-fields-containing-leading-or-trailing-whitespace/16724624 help?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572183/comparison-with-trailing-spaces-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks, nice, so I have to use LIKE instead of =.