# MySQL VARCHAR strange column behavior

Tags: mysql, varchar

I have the following SQL statement which returns a single record as expected:

`select * from geodatasource_cities C,

    geodatasource_countries D 

    where C.CC_FIPS = D.CC_FIPS

    and D.CC_ISO='AU'
 
    and UCASE(TRIM(C.FULL_NAME_ND)) LIKE '%JAN JUE%';`

However, If I use the following SQL statement, no records are returned. I have only changed the LIKE clause to an equal to clause:

`select * from geodatasource_cities C,

    geodatasource_countries D

    where C.CC_FIPS = D.CC_FIPS

    and D.CC_ISO='AU'

    and UCASE(TRIM(C.FULL_NAME_ND)) = 'JAN JUE';`

Can anybody please help me understand why this may be happening?

Similarly, with the following statement:

`select LENGTH(COUNTRY_NAME),

        LENGTH('Australia'),

        COUNTRY_NAME

        from countries

      WHERE UCASE(TRIM(COUNTRY_NAME)) LIKE '%AUSTRALIA%'`

It returns:

10 | 9 | Australia

**EDIT**

Here is a sample of the SQL I used to import the data:

`load data local infile 'CITIES.TXT'

    into table geodatasource_cities

    fields terminated by '\t'

    lines terminated by '\n'

    (CC_FIPS,FULL_NAME_ND);`

It appears as though the \n is wreaking havoc on my data. I will try to import with alternative options tomorrow.

Comment: What is the type of FULL_NAME_ND? Is it a binary string?

Comment: Does UCASE(TRIM(C.FULL_NAME_ND)) LIKE 'JAN JUE' match?

Comment: Yes, the UCASE(TRIM(C.FULL_NAME_ND)) LIKE 'JAN JUE' returns a record whether I use the % in the like statement or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, your requiring an exact match in the database, while in the first case, the name must contain the string "JAN JUE".  Is the full name exactly "JAN JUE" in the database?  You may also need to check your casing.  I know for MS-SQL you can specify your preferred treatment of casing for comparisons.  One selection may be case sensitive while the other is not.

Notes about that for the like clause in MySql:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-like-mysql.aspx

**EDIT**

The MySql Trim() only removes spaces.  So you could have a line break.  (It could also be non breaking spaces, you may need to test to see if trim removes those also, can't find a definitive answer on that.)  Since your getting a different length on fields of one more, I'd suggest checking to make sure your data doesn't have trailing hidden characters like that.

This problem is talked about in this Stack Overflow Question:  [Does the MySQL TRIM function not trim line breaks or carriage returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281724/does-the-mysql-trim-function-not-trim-line-breaks-or-carriage-returns)

Comment: I initially thought it was a case issue, that's why i converted the field FULL_NAME_ND to upper case so I can compare in the same case.

Comment: CRUDE!  Yes with how you've written that, it shouldn't be an issue.  The text for FULL_NAME_ND is just "Jan Jue" right?

Comment: Oh, by the way, "Jan Jue" is in the database. It should actually be, "Jan Juc", which is how I found a problem with the data in the first place, when I went to fix the issue.

Comment: Seems like this may answer the question, I will confirm tomorrow! Thank you!

Comment: Totally imported the data with incorrect parameters, I truncated the table and re-imported with the following sql:


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'CITIES.TXT'
    INTO TABLE cities
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY '\t'
    LINES
        TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;