# Check if value is null, if it is , print nothing, else, print value. Help?

Tags: php, mysql, null

Right, I'm still new to PHP/MySQL and what I've got, even in my head, sounds like it should be simple, but I just can't work out how to write it, here's what I want to happen:

MySQL statement get's the value's of all the cells where the row = id,
PHP then prints them in the appropriate places (this bit I can do),
If a value in said row is null, I don't want it to print ANYTHING related to that value, 
Else, continue as normal.

I.e:

```
-- Other code --

if (value where id = id == null) {

}
else {
Twitter: @Twitter
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to write SQL or PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your exact problem? A simple if statement would do just fine.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM somewhere");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 if($row['someValue'] != '')
 {
  echo $row['someValue'];
 }
}
```

Comment: There's always a possibility that the database contains values that are nothing but white-space. A `trim` might help in that case either in PHP or in SQL. In MySQL trim only apparently works on spaces though.

Comment: I'd have to agree, try to check in your SQL query whether the particular field is empty. This will be more performant.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL you can limit the number of rows that the program has to fetch. To ignore all rows where any of the column values is null, you define a `IS NOT NULL` condition for each column you require to be not null. For example

```
SELECT id, label value 
FROM my_very_special_Table
WHERE id = ?  
  AND label IS NOT NULL
  AND value IS NOT NULL
```

Now there's always a possibilty you have empty string or strings with only white space. MySQL seems to distinguish an empty string from a null value unlike at least Oracle i.e. `'' <> NULL` is true.

In this case you'll have to modify the conditions to make things work properly with `VALUE <> ''` or `LENGTH(VALUE) > 0`. You can add trimming to clear spaces, but in MySQL, [trim doesn't remove any other white-space characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281724/does-the-mysql-trim-function-not-trim-line-breaks-or-carriage-returns). You can also match agains a regular expression but that's probably a bit slow.

If you happen to have both null values and empty strings, you have to cover both scenarios.

Comment: The better solution, anything else is sympton fixing!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you get the data from MySQL into PHP, but if you use a funcion like mysql_fetch_array(), you're value in PHP will be NULL as well:

```
if ([value where id = id] !== null) {
    Twitter: @Twitter;
```