# MySQL Update Text field using TRIM(TRAILING

Tags: mysql

I am trying to remove a carriage return in a MySQL Text type data field using the Update command. I've tried the following and when I export a record and view in a text editor (image attached) I still see this character?  What should I use to remove this?

```
update fort_property_res SET property_information = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM property_information 
update fort_property_res SET property_information = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM property_information
update fort_property_res SET property_information = TRIM(TRAILING '\t' FROM property_information
```

[image: What I see in a text editor]

Comment: Did you check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044316/mysql-removing-trailing-linebreaks-from-a-column

Comment: Might have to to with the order of things... What does `TRIM(TRAILING '\r\n\t' FROM property_information )` do?

Comment: @Wrikken its the last part of the SQL statement, I've updated the question with complete statement

Comment: @user3302748 considering there is not accepted answer and I'm already using TRIM I did not reference it.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco: yes, what I'm saying it if you do an update _per character_, you could have leftovers: consider that a string ending with `...\t\r\n\t\r\n` will be `...\t\r\n` if you do it separately, but without them if you do it in one go with a characters _list_. Also, it may be some other whitespace: what does a `HEX()` of that field end in?

Comment: How do I use HEX @Wrikken?  I think it may be a hidden hex value based on an answer below?

Comment: `SELECT HEX(property_information)` (we're only interested in the last 8 to 16 characters or so, no need for the entire output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harder than it seems as though it should be, yes? Here is a way that works. Perhaps not the best, but it can get you started.

I tried something using rlike and it did not work with my first try. It seems that it should have though. O well.

```
mysql> create table foo (pk int primary key, name varchar(8));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.62 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values (1, 'aaa\t');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.18 sec)

mysql> select * from foo;
+----+------+
| pk | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | aaa   |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update foo set name = substr(name,1,length(name)-1) where hex(name) like '%09';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.23 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from foo;
+----+------+
| pk | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | aaa  |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This has promise but did not work...perhaps because the line break has more text after this?

Comment: ...how do I determine the hex value?