# data not storing properly when i use mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting data from atom xml feed url. I am parsing the data using Rss feed and storing into database. Before storing the data i am using mysql_real_escape_string for every variables.

```
function endElement($parser, $tname) 
{
    if ($tname == "ENTRY") {
    $job_id=explode('job/',$this->id);  
    $job_title1=mysql_real_escape_string($this->title); 
    $job_title=$job_title1;
    } 
}
```

after parsing i am storing data into database

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_job (job_id,job_title) values ('$job_id',' $job_title');
```

I am using table collation as utf8_general_ci. Because i am getting polish and english language text.
This is totally working fine.
But the problem is when i search exact word then i am not getting That work.

Ex: suppose in in table some records job_title as **php developer** when i search that word exactly in query box then i am not getting results.

```
 select * from tbl_jobs where job_title like 'php developer'
```

when i use % then i am getting results.

```
select * from tbl_jobs where job_title like 'php developer%'
```

But the job_title contains exactly **php developer** but results not coming

When i remove MySQL_real_escape_string and store the data then i am getting results correctly. I am getting exact results. But  at the time of storing data into database after some records storing, storing stopped bacause of quotations in data.

Please help me hoe to solve this issue.

Comment: sorry. that is not a problem at the time of typing i added that one

Comment: are you using innodb or myisam?

Comment: MyIsam.  Because i am using FULL TEXT search also

Comment: do you set your mysql character set before using mysql_real_escape_string like stated here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php under "Security: the default character set" ?

Comment: Don't use mysql_query, don't use mysql_real_escape_string, use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements.

Comment: Since the job title contains exactly "php developer", and by exactly you probably mean only that phrase nothing more or less is stored in database, why do you use "like" in your query? select* from tbl_jobs where job_title = 'php developer'. If in job_title is something more than "php developer" then you should use like but with %% symbols

Comment: and as @Jonast92 proposes why on earth you still use mysql_query use PDO or mysqli. But if you ask my opinion use PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data might be saved as any new line characters or tab characters with spaces.

Use **REPLACE**. This drops all carriage returns and line-feeds:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(log, '\r', ''), '\n', '') FROM test;
```

If you only want to drop trailing carriage returns and
line-feeds, you can use TRIM instead:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '\r\n' FROM log) FROM test;
```

This link might be useful to you [MySQL Removing trailing linebreaks from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044316/mysql-removing-trailing-linebreaks-from-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you should do is use the PHP PDO. It's more easy to use and all Oriented Object, which makes you programming more fast and clean.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Although this _might help_ OP it does not really provide an answer to the question.