# remove trailing whitespace in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Why does my SELECT not ignore whitespace, and why does TRIM seem to have no effect?**

Here are the partial results of something like `SELECT DISTINCT crop_year from raw_data`:

```
Rows    crop_year
105755  '2010'
12326   '2010 '
256363  '2011'
319321  '2011 '
...
```

I typed in the single quotes to illustrate the fact that there is trailing whitespace.

I have 2 problems here on my production server... which I cannot replicate locally:

A. I expect `SELECT` to ignore whitespace, as explained in numerous other questions, as well as the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html), but it clearly does not work this way on my prod server.

B. I expect `UPDATE raw_data SET crop_year = TRIM(crop_year)` to fix the problem, but running this query results in 0 affected rows.

Other background:
This column type is VARCHAR(11).
If it's relevant, the table contains mixed storage engines and collations: this table is MyISAM, and this column is currently latin1_swedish_ci.

PS: In this specific case, year is always a 4 digit value, so I eventually changed the column from a VARCHAR(11) to CHAR(4)... which effectively trimmed the whitespace, but I am still posting the question because I find it likely that I will encounter a similar problem on other columns which are not of a fixed length.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281724/does-the-mysql-trim-function-not-trim-line-breaks-or-carriage-returns).  TRIM does not respect all whitespace... just spaces.  In my case, I needed:

`select distinct trim(BOTH '\r' from crop_year) as crop_year FROM raw_field_data`

Other variations could include

`select distinct trim(BOTH '\n' from crop_year) as crop_year FROM raw_field_data` or
`select distinct trim(BOTH '\n\r' from crop_year) as crop_year FROM raw_field_data`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you place extra space in your "form" when you enter the value on the crop year. check your input forms maybe...